# Recommended lifecycle for services using SignalR hubs

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm injecting following service with the SignalR ContentHub in various controllers in a ASP.NET Core web application (running on .NET Core 2.2). Currently the service is injected with a transient lifecycle. Using singleton lifecycle would be better? Is the transient lifecycle in this case a possible source for performance issues?

```
public class PushMessageService : IPushMessageService
{
    private readonly ILogger<PushMessageService> _logger;
    private readonly IHubContext<ContentHub> _context;

    public PushMessageService(
        ILogger<PushMessageService> logger,
        IHubContext<ContentHub> context
    )
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }    

    public async Task Push(int productId)
    {
        var msg = new Message
        {
            ProductId = productId
        };

        await SendAsync("PushMsg", productId, msg);
    }

    private async Task SendAsync<TPayload>(string methodName, int productId, TPayload payload)
    {
        await _context.Clients.Group("prod" + productId).SendAsync(methodName, payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IHubContext` abstraction that wraps the hub is a singleton. As such, the lifetime of the class using it as a dependency doesn't really matter. Whether you use a singleton, scoped, or transient lifetime, you always get the same instance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0#get-an-instance-of-ihubcontext
n ASP.NET Core SignalR, you can access an instance of IHubContext via dependency injection. You can inject an instance of IHubContext into a controller, middleware, or other DI service. Use the instance to send messages to clients.

 Note

This differs from ASP.NET 4.x SignalR which used GlobalHost to provide access to the IHubContext. ASP.NET Core has a dependency injection framework that removes the need for this global singleton.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR expects the Hub to be created separately for each message. You need to add it as a Transient service if you want your Hub to be in DI. You generally shouldn't resolve the Hub out of DI. If you need to share code between your Hub and some other component, I'd suggest using either `IHubContext` or putting the shared code in a separate DI service as you doing here. So I believe that this should be a transient.